# Grammar using SLLGEN library

Tags: scheme, racket, grammar, interpreter

I am new with scheme language.

I tried to expand some  grammar rules of the orignal SLLGEN given by EoPL programmers.

So, in order to support interpreter to recognize nested lists, I added the following grammar rule in "lang.scm":

```
 (expression 
  ("cons" "("
          (arbno expression (arbno",")) 
          ")")        
  lst-exp)
```

in addition I added a suitable function in "interp.scm".

I have no problems in running flat list.
The problems occuers in nested list.
For example I tried to run the following command:

```
(run "cons (1 ,cons(3 2))")
```

and the racket interpreter shows the following massage:

```
*cases: not a expval: (3 2)*
```

It seem to me that it does not recoginze the the numbers "3" and "2" as a numbers. Instead he took the all expression as string.

How can I change my grammar in order to avoid this problem?

I attached the relevant datatype of "expval" mentioned in "data-structure.scm":

```
(define-datatype expval expval?
  (num-val
    (value number?))
  (bool-val
    (boolean boolean?))
  (lst-val
   (lst pair?)))
```

Comment: Do you have a complete program we can try?

Comment: ... or at least a link to the library you are modifying?

Comment: I suspect he asks us to solve him a homework that looks like [this](https://www2.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/383/havens/notes/Lecture11.pdf). Something like yacc.

Comment: https://docs.racket-lang.org/eopl/index.html